# Including study as a moderator in a meta-analytical model

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I'm trying to figure out what it means to include 'study' as a moderator in a meta-analytical model. In the R package metafor, for example, we might build an intercept-only random effects model as such:

```r
library(orchard) 
data(english)
english_MA1 <- rma.mv(yi = SMD, V = vSMD, 
                 random = list(~1 | StudyNo, ~1 | EffectID), 
                 data = english)
```

This model is based on having multiple effect sizes per study. What would be the significance of then adapting this to a mixed effects model with study included as a moderator, as such:

```r
english_MA2 <- rma.mv(yi = SMD, V = vSMD, mods=StudyNo, 
                      random = list(~1 | StudyNo, ~1 | EffectID), 
                      data = english)
```

Does this tell you anything/is this a valid model? I'm sure it's simple but I don't see anyone using study as a moderator and I'm wondering why. Furthermore, if one identifies heterogeneity in t first model, will we necessarily find a moderator effect in the latter? I'm sure I'm just having a brain fart but I'm a bit stumped on this one.